# One View page, 2 exposed filters block

Tags: 7, views

I have content type recipes and a view page that list all of my recipe nodes, that view has an exposed filter block that i placed in header. So in header i have views exposed filter ( search terms ) that works as recipe finder.

Now on that view page with results i want to add more exposed filters (3 select drop down) that will filter my selected taxonomies.

Problem is  if i just add those filters in my view, they will all show up in same block in header, but there i need just search.

Is there a way to have just 1 exposed filter in block and others on a view page.

Comment: I tired solutions from that questions but they didnt work. I clone a page and put exposed filter there but when i do search nothing happens, like i didnt searched anything.

Comment: @Alex the fact that answers don't satisfy you does not mean questions are not duplicates. If you want to ask why your implementation of certain answer fail, it'll be a different matter. But for now, they are duplicates.